# PHP/MYSQL image delete button

Tags: php, mysql

Hello im still a beginner but i have a uni project that i have to complete.I have to make a php/mysql image gallery and i have to add a DELETE button on each image, when clicked it needs to delete the image from the page and from the database.I have looked up everywhere but im not sure how exactly to write the code in order to delete the images, i have created the button and i have linked it to delete-image.php.
Any recommendations ?

view-album.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_GET['album_id'])) {
$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
$get_album = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_albums WHERE album_id = $album_id");
$album_data = $get_album->fetch_assoc();
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $album_data['album_name'] ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$photo_count = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $album_id");
?>
<a href="index.php">Home</a> | <?php echo $album_data['album_name'] ?> (<?php echo $photo_count->num_rows; ?>)<br><br>


<form method="post" action="upload-photo.php?album_id=<?php echo $album_id ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Add photo to this album:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="photo" /> <input type="submit" name="upload-photo" value="Upload" />
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['upload_action'])) {
if ($_GET['upload_action'] == "success") { ?>
<br><br>Photo successfully added to this album!<br><br>
<?php }
}
?>
<?php
$photos = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $album_id");
while($photo_data = $photos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $photo_data['photo_link'] ?>" width="200px" height="200px" />

<form method="POST" action="delete-image.php">
    <button name='delete'>Delete file </button>
</form>

<?php }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

delete-image.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';



    ?>
```

Comment: 1) your delete form needs a hidden field containing the ID of the row to delete from the database. 2) in the PHP you read that value from $_POST, 3) write a SQL DELETE query to delete the row, 4) use the unlink function to delete the path (you may need a SELECT just before the delete query, to get the exact file path from the DB again)

Comment: have your problem is solved or not?.

Comment: @kam1kaze3 what problem are you getting??

Comment: @kam1kaze3 have you successfully passed the hidden row id with button.

Comment: Yes, i have done exactly what you said and it looks like exactly like the answer below,i created hidden id and i updated the delete-image.php, but when i click the delete button it just redirects me to delete-image.php and nothing else happens, the images are not deleted neither in the database nor on the page,i  believe i should use the unlink function to delete the images from the page, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1.)First you have to create input hidden field with row `id` with every button Tag.

(2.)Get `id` from hidden field in delete_image.php by `$_POST[''];` POST method.

(3.)then delete the image from that `id`.

```
<?php
    $photos = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $album_id");
    while($photo_data = $photos->fetch_assoc()) { 
             $album_id = $photo_data['album_id'];  
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $photo_data['photo_link']; ?>" width="200px" height="200px" />
    
    <form method="POST" action="delete-image.php">
         <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="$album_id">   // hidden input field with id.
        <button name='delete'>Delete file </button>
    </form>
    
    <?php }
    ?>
```

**delete-image.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$idget = $_POST['delete'];  // get here hidden id by POST method.
$photosDelete = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $idget");

?>
```

**Note:-** For More information regarding `hidden field` see this:-

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp

Comment: I updated my code with the hidden id, but im still not able to delete them, when i click the delete file button nothing happens